# problema con la creaccion de un archivo

Tags: c#, .net

tengo un problema cuando creo un archivo con StreamWriter y otros derivados, cuando creo el archivo me lo pone formato UNIX

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y necesito que cree el archivo con formato DOS/windows
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya eh intentado usar System.Environment.NewLine, \r\n, ASCII y el metodo replace
alguna alternativa a usar o si es un problema con la configuracion de mi visual studio
gracias

Comment: System.Environment.NewLine usa el salto de linea del sistema operativo. Donde es quee estas mirando el archivo que sale con otra codificacion?

Comment: windows 
incluso cuando creo un archivo desde cero es decir un string cualquiera me pone formato UNIX al crear el archivo

Comment: con que estas abriendo el archivo? no lo estara convirtiendo tu lector de archivos a formato unix? me pasaba usando ultraedit 32 que hacia la transformacion automatica...

Answer (score 0):

Como pudiste ver, por defecto [`StreamWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter) usa el finalizador de línea del sistema operativo .

Afortunadamente cada instancia de la clase cuenta con una propiedad llamada [`NewLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.textwriter.newline#system-io-textwriter-newline) que puedes establecer para cambiar este comportamiento.

Para cambiar a CRLF es tan sencillo como escribir la siguiente línea antes de efectuar cualquier operación sobre el `StreamWriter`.

```
streamWriter.NewLine = "\r\n";
```

Lo mismo aplica a cualquier clase que herede de [`TextWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.textwriter).